# Laravel Mix SCSS to it's Own CSS File

Tags: npm, webpack, sass, yarnpkg, laravel-mix

I'm using Yarn and Laravel Mix with Webpack to compile my SASS files to CSS and also to compile my JavaScript files. Everything is fine but how can I make it so that every .scss file has it's own .css in the same folder?

For example:

```
assets/styles/components/component1.scss
assets/styles/components/component1.css
```

-- and --

```
assets/styles/layouts/homepage.scss
assets/styles/layouts/homepage.css
```

So far, my `webpack.mix.js` file looks like this:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const webpack = require('webpack');

mix.setPublicPath(path.resolve('./'))
   .webpackConfig({
     plugins: [
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
         $: "jquery",
         jQuery: "jquery"
       })
     ]
   })
   .copyDirectory('assets/images', 'dist/images')
   .copyDirectory('assets/fonts', 'dist/fonts')
   .sass('assets/styles/app.scss', 'dist/css', { outputStyle: 'compressed' })
   .version()
   .options({
     processCssUrls: false,
     uglify: {
       uglifyOptions: {
         output: {
           max_line_len: false,
           beautify: false
         }
       }
     }
   });

if( process.env.NODE_ENV ) {
  require(`${__dirname}/webpack.mix.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`);
}
```

I am using:

- Yarn 1.12.3
- NNode.js v10.14.1
- NPM 6.4.1
- Laravel Mix 3.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Multiple .sass() for multiple files and change the directory.

```
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.sass('resources/sass/other.scss', 'public/other/css')
.sass('resources/sass/yetanother.scss','public/other2/css');
```